# wpf - templates - pass template item as ConverterParameter

Tags: wpf, data-binding, resources, binding

I have a template for a ListBox.  In the ListBox I have a template on the ListBoxItems.  I want to disable some of these items (I am still working on what I want to use to make the "event" fire, so I have just put in IsSelected for now)

My issue is that I need to get at some of the data for the ListBoxItem to know if it should be disabled or not (ie, which one are we looking at right now...)

I thought I would use ConverterProperty, but it seems to only allow Resources and hard coded values (I can't databind with out reflection, which I don't want to do).

I tried to pass in RelativeSource Self and the ConverterParameter and that just passed in an object of type RelativeSource that would not cast to ListBoxItem.

Any ideas?

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxListStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Converter={StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">

                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a multi-binding instead of your binding, then you can bind to more than one parameter.

[ms doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) on multibinding

Comment: its funny, ive done this a couple of times (trying to bind a converter parameter) before remembering about multi-bindings :)